# Minimizing a quadratic function using gradient descent

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I have the following function

$$f(x,y) = (x + y − 1)^2 + (x − 2y)^2 + (2x − 4y + 3)^2$$

Could you suggest the best way to choose the step-size? And is $f(x,y)$ strongly convex? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why even use gradient descent? Just compute the gradient and find where it vanishes.

Comment: So there is other way to solve this optimization problem besides applying gradient descent method?

Comment: Sure. The function is quadratic and the gradient is linear in $x$ and $y$. You will end up with a system of $2$ linear equations in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Ah ok. However if I want to use gradient descent method, how to set up an efficient step-size?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we are given a *convex* quadratic function

$$f (\mathrm x) := \frac 12 \mathrm x^\top \mathrm A \,\mathrm x - \mathrm b^\top \mathrm x + c$$

where matrix $\rm A$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite. The gradient of $f$ is

$$\nabla f (\mathrm x) = \mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b$$

Using **gradient descent** with step $\mu$,

$$\begin{array}{rl}\mathrm x_{k+1} &= \mathrm x_k - \mu \nabla f (\mathrm x_k)\\ &= \mathrm x_k - \mu \left( \mathrm A \mathrm x_k - \mathrm b \right)\\ &= \left( \mathrm I - \mu \mathrm A \right) \mathrm x_k + \mu \mathrm b\end{array}$$

Lastly, choose step $\mu$ such that the (real) eigenvalues of $\mathrm I - \mu \mathrm A$ are in the open interval $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your function can be written as,
$$f(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}^{\top}\begin{bmatrix}6 & -9 \\ -9 & 21\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}10 \\ -26\end{bmatrix}^{\top}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} + 10$$

The Hessian of this function is,
$$\nabla^2f = 2\begin{bmatrix}6 & -9 \\ -9 & 21\end{bmatrix}$$

This Hessian is positive definite (quite easy to prove using [Sylvester's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion) or just computing the eigenvalues). Therefore, yes, your function is strongly convex.

Instead of using gradient descent, you can directly solve by taking the gradient and setting it to zero,
$$\nabla f = 2\begin{bmatrix}6 & -9 \\ -9 & 21\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}10 \\ -26\end{bmatrix}$$

Setting this to zero would give us,
$$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}6 & -9 \\ -9 & 21\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}-10 \\ 26\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{15}\begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 11\end{bmatrix}$$