# Minimizing $f (x, y)= (x − y)^2 + 1 − x$ using gradient descent

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, quadratic-programming

How can we minimize $$f (x, y)= (x − y)^2 + 1 − x$$ using the gradient descent method? I need to write software code for this.

Comment: Do you have a clear representation in mind of what gradient descent means in this case ? If I say that the gradient is always orthogonal to "level sets" of a certain surface, here a paraboloid, do these words are meaningful for you ?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2686385/339790)

Comment: $f(x,x) = 1 - x$, which has no minimum over $x \in \Bbb R$. Are there restrictions on the values of $x, y$ that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: No answer to my questions ? Are you interested by having your problem solved by others without any exchange ?